# YAML invalid - maybe quote marks issue

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, quoting

I am getting the error info from Gitlab CI/CD Pipelines: `yaml invalid`. The problem is being caused by the fifth line of `.gitlab-ci.yml` script:

```
   - 'ssh deployer@gitadam.ga \'rm /var/www/html/hosts/production/current/temp__*\''
```

The section of the script

```
script:
    - 'pwd'
    - 'whoami'
    - 'ls temp__*'
    - 'ssh deployer@gitadam.ga \'rm /var/www/html/hosts/production/current/temp__*\''
    - 'if ls temp__* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then for file in temp__*; do scp $file deployer@gitadam.ga:/var/www/html/hosts/production/current/; done; fi'
```

How to fix the line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just leave in the start and end single quotes, no need to use brute force and remove them all. **This could lead to other errors (although not in your case here), and in your case is not enough to get the result you want**.¹

The real problem is that you try to escape single quotes within a single-quoted scalar the wrong way. The only character that can, and needs to be, escaped within a single-quoted scalar, is the single quote. So that cannot be done by using a backslash, as you did, because then the backslash would need escaping as well within single-quoted scalars.

*To escape a single quote within a single quoted scalar, you need to double/repeat it*.²

In the [YAML specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097) the wording is slightly different, to the same effect:

> The single-quoted style is specified by surrounding “'” indicators. Therefore, within a single-quoted scalar, such characters need to be repeated. This is the only form of escaping performed in single-quoted scalars. In particular, the “\” and “"” characters may be freely used.

So to change line 5, just change both backslashes to single quotes:

```
script:
    - 'pwd'
    - 'whoami'
    - 'ls temp__*'
    - 'ssh deployer@gitadam.ga ''rm /var/www/html/hosts/production/current/temp__*'''
    - 'if ls temp__* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then for file in temp__*; do scp $file deployer@gitadam.ga:/var/www/html/hosts/production/current/; done; fi'
```

Within *double* quoted scalars in YAML you can escape with backslashes to get a double quote, but also all kind of special characters, or to facilitate YAML features. However [single quotes are not escapable that way](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092). Line five would need to have its backslashes removed if you would use double quotes:

```
    - "ssh deployer@gitadam.ga 'rm /var/www/html/hosts/production/current/temp__*'"
```

There are multiple reasons to keep the quotes. If any of your scalars would have started with a special (for YAML) character, you would need quoting. It is not enough that a scalar starts with a letter (`A-Za-z`): if the scalar would have happen to have special sequences, like the comment start sequence ( space + octothorpe ) or value indicator ( colon + space ) sequence embedded, then you have to use quotes as well.

Using single quotes is safer than not using them, and the only thing you need to know when using them is how to escape them. They might sometimes be superfluous, but *they are the simplest way (with regards to number of exceptions you need to take into account) to define a scalar string in your YAM*L.

---

¹<sub>You would need to remove the backslashes as in line 5 as well, if you remove the leading and trailing single quotes.</sub>

²<sub>Here "it" refers to the single quote, of course not the whole scalar.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You should probably try it yourself once without the quotes, before posting it here.

But yeah, seems it's because of that.

```
script:
  - pwd
  - whoami
  - ls temp__*
  - ssh deployer@gitadam.ga 'rm /var/www/html/hosts/production/current/temp__*'
  - if ls temp__* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then for file in temp__*; do scp $file deployer@gitadam.ga:/var/www/html/hosts/production/current/; done; fi
```

GitLab also has a built in linter for their ci syntax

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option to format ssh commands on the GitLab CI might be:

```
job:
  script:
    - >
      ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host bash -s << 'EOF'
        echo "test"
        echo "test2"
      EOF
```